# Java entering value in non-primitive data types

Tags: java, type-conversion

Could someone explain to me how reference (non-primitive) data types works?   Mainly how to input data into them and how to check what data they are holding? 
Could you use this code as an example please.

```
public class Example{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Circle c= new Circle();
        System.out.println():
    }
}

public class Circle{
    Circle round;
    public Circle(){
    }
    public Circle numPlacment(){
        round=new Circle(2);     //I would like circle to contain the value of '2'
        return round;
    }
    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder b= new StringBuilder();
        b.append(round);
        return String.format("%4s",b);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"The following example code is what's confusing me...."`-- please be specific. What exactly about the code is confusing you?

Comment: `"I think it has something to do with the constructor but I am not sure."` -- in this tells us little to help us understand your problem. Your Circle constructor does nothing, and your constructor call doesn't compile.

Comment: ... and why does your Circle class contain a Circle instance variable, round? This code and question is very confusing.

Comment: I am trying to place data (the number 2) into the variable round but because it is 'Circle' and not a integer or String I am having trouble doing it.

Comment: You don't do this by giving Circle a Circle variable. You instead give it an int variable to hold the 2 value.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is somewhat nonsensical. It may be easier just to look at how it's supposed to be done:

```
public class Example{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        // create a new circle with radius 2
        Circle c= new Circle(2);  
        // Print that circle
        System.out.println(c);    
    }
}

class Circle {
    // The instance variable that stores the radius for this circle
    double radius;

    // Create a new Circle given a radius
    public Circle(double radius) {
      // assign the given radius parameter to the instance variable
      this.radius = radius;
    }
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder b= new StringBuilder();
        b.append(radius);
        return String.format("%4s",b);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you did here, but what if the radius was to be generated randomly. How could we place the radius into 'c' from the Circle class not main

Comment: @user2737810: simply give Circle a `setRadius(int r)` method, and let other classes that hold a Circle instance, call this method when the radius needs to change. This is all explained in the first 2 chapters of any intro to Java book. Consider reading one, or doing as I did when starting out, read 3 to 4. 1+.